# Можно ли сделать ImageView больше размера экрана?

Tags: android

Есть ImageView и его src - довольно большая картинка. Возможно ли сделать ImageWiew больше, чем экран смартфона (DeviceScreen)? Если да, то как? Так сказать, больше, чем match_parent.

Comment: wrap_content не катит? Если можно, дайте ссылку.

Comment: Хорошо бы, чтобы ImageView был таким: https://yadi.sk/i/07baqhLHdDGKU
 (Красный прямоугольник)

Comment: А можно спросить, для чего вам нужно это? Просто я подозреваю, что вам можно было обойтись заданием scaleType.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблему решил с помощью указания отрицательного marginLeft="-300dp"(к примеру).

Comment: Кстати да, логично.  
У Вас случайно опыта с фрагментами нет? Может, подскажите по моему вопросу
http://hashcode.ru/questions/381466/json-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-listfragment-android